One to one homomorphism from $\mathbb Z$ to $\prod _{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$
Does there exist a one- to- one $\mathbb Z$- homomorphism from $\mathbb Z$ to $\prod _{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ ?
If such a homomorphism exists, we can resort to the injectivity of $\mathbb Q$ and the embedding of $\mathbb Z$  to $\mathbb Q$ to get a nonzero $\mathbb Z$- homomorphism from $\prod _{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Q$.
Thanks for any help!

There is a 1-1 homomorphism of $\Bbb{Z}$ into $\prod_{i=1}^\infty\Bbb{Z}/i\Bbb{Z}$ (the homomorphism is the product of all the projection functions).

Every homomorphism $\prod \mathbb{Z}/2 \to \mathbb{Q}$ is zero, because every element of the source is $2$-torsion and $\mathbb{Q}$ is torsion-free.

Hint: $\prod_I \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is $2$-torsion but $\mathbb{Z}$ is not.
